# deriving variables used in the first component of PCA

Tags: matlab, pca

I'm sorry for asking this kind of question (probably the answer is obvious, but of course I don't know it) :)

I'm using `pca` function in matlab.
is there a way to know from which variables the first score is calculated?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't each score just a linear combination of the original variables?

Comment: A column of 1,2,3 would mean 1 * var1 + 2 * var2 + 3 * var3

Comment: it's not clear to me...
I've my data matrix that is 1068x192 and I get a score that is 1068x192 as well ...
I would like to know which variables from my data matrix have been used to compute the first column of the score matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `[coeff,scores] = pca(X);`,  the weights of each variable for the first principal component are,

```
coeff(:,1)
```

Every variable goes into the computation of every principal component (hence, `coeff` is a square matrix), but the final contribution of some variables can be very small.  To find the big contributors, `find(coeff(:,1)>THRESH)`.